# alternative to facebook offline access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a facebook application that will scan a users' news feed on a daily basis - but the offline access token has been deprecated.

I know that the access token can be extended to 60 days. So if a user doesn't use my application for 60 days, would I be not able to access their information after that?

I read the developers section but didn't understand it properly.

Comment: _“So if a user doesn't use my application for 60 days,would i [not be able] to access his information after that?”_ – No, you won’t. – _“i read the developers section but didn't understand it properly.”_ – then read it again. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ + https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly the point. You'll need to code your app to run through an authentication flow if the access token expires. Remember, the access token can expire for other (legitimate) reasons, other than timeout. If you're not asking for new permissions, and need to grab a new access tokens, the flow should happen without any user actions required.

You'll need to code for access tokens failing regardless of offline_access - so do it right! :)